# Is there a way to make an AND operation over a column of TINYINT(1) in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, boolean, tinyint

I got the following table and I need to return 1 if all rows have disponibilidad = 1

[image: EXAMPLE TABLE]

The following QUERY works just fine, but i was looking for a more efficient way of doing it.

QUERY:

```
SELECT IF(AVG(disponibilidad) < 1, 0, 1) AS newResult
FROM pasteleria.compone
RIGHT JOIN pasteleria.ingredientes
    ON pasteleria.compone.id_ingrediente = pasteleria.ingredientes.id_ingrediente
WHERE id_componente = 1;
```

RESULT:

[image: RESULT]

As I see it, with an 'AND' it would be far more efficient, since it wouldn't have to do AVG().

Comment: What's the point of `AVG` without group by ?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_avg

Comment: It's just an example query that works at the moment, if the AVG of values is lower than 1 it means that at least 1 of them is 0.

Comment: I think you should use `having` clause instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql does not support a boolean AND aggregate function like Postgresql's `bool_and`.

Why not a simple `MIN()`:

```
SELECT MIN(disponibilidad) AS newResult
FROM pasteleria.compone
RIGHT JOIN pasteleria.ingredientes
    ON pasteleria.compone.id_ingrediente = pasteleria.ingredientes.id_ingrediente
WHERE id_componente = 1;
```

This will return 1 only if all values of the column are 1 (provided the column is not nullable) and 0 if there is at least one row with 0.

Comment: Nice one, better than what i had but still not the answer i was looking for

Comment: @felipesoto MySql does not support an aggregate AND function. This is why I posted MIN as a solution.

Comment: I understand, add that to your answer to accept it as solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0,0,1) AS newResult
FROM pasteleria.compone
RIGHT JOIN pasteleria.ingredientes
    ON pasteleria.compone.id_ingrediente = pasteleria.ingredientes.id_ingrediente
WHERE id_componente = 1
AND disponibilidad <> 1
```

so that if there are any rows where disponibilidad is *not* 1, you output 0, otherwise if it's zero (so all disponibilidad values are 1) you output 1?

Comment: It's pretty much the same solution as with AVG()